# Rewrite URL of Custom Post Type for Jobs

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add a unique ID for a custom post type called jobs, as some jobs may have the same name but I don't want them to have urls like: engineer, engineer-2 etc.

I have used the code below to get the post ID but I want to append it to the url, not prepend as it currently is doing.

```
// Rewrite permalink structure
function jobs_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $queryarg = 'post_type=jobs&p=';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%cpt_id%', '([^/]+)', $queryarg );
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'jobs', '/jobs/%cpt_id%/', false );
}
add_action( 'init', 'jobs_rewrite' );

function jobs_permalink( $post_link, $id = 0, $leavename ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    global $post;
    if ( is_wp_error( $post ) )
        return $post;
        $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct( 'jobs' );
        $newlink = str_replace( '%cpt_id%', $post->ID . '-' . $post->post_name, $newlink );
        $newlink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $newlink ) );
    return $newlink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'jobs_permalink', 1, 3);
```

I've tried swapping this line:

```
$newlink = str_replace( '%cpt_id%', $post->ID . '-' . $post->post_name, $newlink );
```

To:

```
$newlink = str_replace( '%cpt_id%', $post->post_name . '-' . $post->ID, $newlink );
```

But when I do this the post is not found. The structure I want is something like this:

www.example.com/jobs/engineer-12

But what I'm getting is this:

www.example.com/jobs/12-engineer

Basically each URL needs to be unique.

Another way I envisioned this was to use a unique job ID (custom meta field) that is appended to the URL. I was able to achieve this using custom fields but didn't quite get the desired result.

Basically at this point I just want to know how I can get the ID at the end instead of at the beginning of the slug.

Thanks

Comment: Did you flush the rewrite rules? You need to flush the rules every time you change something to the permalinks structure. You can do so by going to **Settings --> Permalinks --> Save changes**

Comment: @bynicolas Yes, I did. It doesnt work in this case. I don't understand it to be honest. The link just takes me to the jobs archive but not the single job item.